# How to join two separate mirrored objects

Tags: sculpting, shrinkwrap, mirror-modifier

I’ve sculpted two heads seperate withe the Mirror modifier. Also the shrink wrap is Al over the two objects. If I join them, the points don’t clip and I can’t merge the points, because the mirror modifier isn’t on the same side. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Difficult to imagine what you're talking about without some images! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hello, Sarah, and welcome. It is _very_ hard to understand what you might mean in this question. As John has commented, a  descriptive image of your situation may help   us get there.